# Event binding on dynamically created elements can not work

Tags: jquery, dynamic, bind, element

I am working on shopping cart and I store the good info in session.
I use ajax to create the shopping cart in html page, with this I can add good to the shopping cart and it works.but when I want to delete good from the shopping cart it can not work.also, I must refresh the page to delete the good.
my code is as following:
cart.php

```
 class CartController extends Controller {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        // session(null);
        if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
            $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
        }
    }

    public function index(){
        kd($_SESSION);
    }

    public  function addItem(){
        /*
         * TODO --- 安全方面的考虑
         */
        $good_id = intval(I('post.good_id'));

        if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$good_id])){
            $_SESSION['cart'][$good_id]['good_num'] += 1;
            $html = '';
            $total_price = 0;
            foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $k=>$v){
                $total_price += $v['good_price']*$v['good_num'];
                $html .= '<div class="shoppingCartProductWrapper"> <a  href="' . U('mall/index/gooddetail',array('id'=>$v['good_id'])) . '" class="shoppingCartProductImageWrapper">'.'<img src="'.$v['good_image'].'" class="shoppingCartProductImage" alt=""/></a><div class="shoppingCartProductInfoWrapper"> <a href="'.U('mall/index/gooddetail',array('id'=>$v['good_id'])).'" class="shoppingCartProductTitle">'.$v['good_name'].'</a><div class="shoppingCartProductButtonsWrapper"><input type="text" id="shoppingCartProductNumber-1" class="shoppingCartProductNumber" name="product-1" value="'.$v['good_num'].'" /><span class="shoppingCartProductPrice">'.$v['good_price'].'</span><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="shoppingCartRemoveProductButton"></a> </div></div></div>';
            }
            $html .= '<div class="shoppingCartInfoWrapper"><span class="shoppingCartProductsNumber">商品数量:'.count($_SESSION['cart']) . '</span><span class="shoppingCartProductsTotal">Total: ￥'.$total_price.'</span></div>';
            exit($html);
        }
        $good_name = I('post.good_name');
        $good_price = I('post.good_price');        
        $good_image = I('post.good_image');
        $good_num = intval(I('post.good_num'));
        $good = compact('good_id', 'good_name', 'good_price', 'good_image', 'good_num');
        $_SESSION['cart'][$good_id] = $good;

        $html = '';
        $total_price = 0;
        foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $k=>$v){
            $total_price += $v['good_price']*$v['good_num'];
            $html .= '<div class="shoppingCartProductWrapper"> <a  href="' . U('mall/index/gooddetail',array('id'=>$v['good_id'])) . '" class="shoppingCartProductImageWrapper">'.'<img src="'.$v['good_image'].'" class="shoppingCartProductImage" alt=""/></a><div class="shoppingCartProductInfoWrapper"> <a href="'.U('mall/index/gooddetail',array('id'=>$v['good_id'])).'" class="shoppingCartProductTitle">'.$v['good_name'].'</a><div class="shoppingCartProductButtonsWrapper"><input type="text" id="shoppingCartProductNumber-1" class="shoppingCartProductNumber" name="product-1" value="'.$v['good_num'].'" /><span class="shoppingCartProductPrice">'.$v['good_price'].'</span><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="shoppingCartRemoveProductButton"></a> </div></div></div>';
        }
        $html .= '<div class="shoppingCartInfoWrapper"><span class="shoppingCartProductsNumber">商品数量:'.count($_SESSION['cart']) . '</span><span class="shoppingCartProductsTotal">Total: ￥'.$total_price.'</span></div>';

        exit($html);
    }

    public function removeItem(){
        $good_id = intval(I('post.good_id'));
        unset($_SESSION['cart'][$good_id]);

        $html = '';
        $total_price = 0;
        foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $k=>$v){
            $total_price += $v['good_price']*$v['good_num'];
            $html .= '<div class="shoppingCartProductWrapper"> <a  href="' . U('mall/index/gooddetail',array('id'=>$v['good_id'])) . '" class="shoppingCartProductImageWrapper">'.'<img src="'.$v['good_image'].'" class="shoppingCartProductImage" alt=""/></a><div class="shoppingCartProductInfoWrapper"> <a href="'.U('mall/index/gooddetail',array('id'=>$v['good_id'])).'" class="shoppingCartProductTitle">'.$v['good_name'].'</a><div class="shoppingCartProductButtonsWrapper"><input type="text" id="shoppingCartProductNumber-1" class="shoppingCartProductNumber" name="product-1" value="'.$v['good_num'].'" /><span class="shoppingCartProductPrice">'.$v['good_price'].'</span><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="shoppingCartRemoveProductButton"></a> </div></div></div>';
        }
        $html .= '<div class="shoppingCartInfoWrapper"><span class="shoppingCartProductsNumber">商品数量:'.count($_SESSION['cart']) . '</span><span class="shoppingCartProductsTotal">Total: ￥'.$total_price.'</span></div>';
        exit($html);
    }
}
```

shoppcart.html

```
<!-- shopping cart wrapper start -->
<form id="shoppingCartWrapper" class="shoppingCartWrapper" action="#" method="post">
  <fieldset>        
    <?php 
      $total_price = 0;
      foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $k=>$v){
        $total_price += $v['good_price']*intval($v['good_num']);
    ?>
    <!-- shopping cart product starts -->
    <div class="shoppingCartProductWrapper"> 
      <a href="<?php echo DOMAIN.'/mall/index/gooddetail/id/'.$v['good_id'].'.html'; ?>" class="shoppingCartProductImageWrapper">
        <img src="<?php echo $v['good_image']; ?>" class="shoppingCartProductImage" alt=""/>
      </a>
      <div class="shoppingCartProductInfoWrapper"> 
        <a href="<?php echo DOMAIN.'/mall/index/gooddetail/id/'.$v['good_id'].'.html'; ?>" class="shoppingCartProductTitle"><?php echo $v['good_name']; ?></a>
        <div class="shoppingCartProductButtonsWrapper">
          <input type="text" class="shoppingCartProductNumber" name="product-3" value="<?php echo $v['good_num']; ?>"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="good_id" value="<?php echo $v['good_id']; ?>" />
          <span class="shoppingCartProductPrice">￥<?php echo $v['good_price']; ?></span><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="shoppingCartRemoveProductButton"></a> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- shopping cart product ends --> 
    <?php } ?>

    <!-- shopping cart info wrapper starts -->
    <div class="shoppingCartInfoWrapper"> 
      <span class="shoppingCartProductsNumber">商品数量: <?php echo count($_SESSION['cart']); ?></span> 
      <span class="shoppingCartProductsTotal">Total: ￥<?php echo $total_price; ?></span> 
    </div>
    <!-- shopping cart info wrapper ends -->

    <div id="shoppingCartButtons" class="shoppingCartButtonsWrapper"><a href="" class="shoppingCartEmptyButton">清空</a>
      <input type="submit" value="去付款" id="shoppingCartCheckoutButton" class="shoppingCartCheckoutButton"/>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<!-- shopping cart wrapper ends --> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      remove_url = "{:U('mall/cart/removeitem')}";
      $('#shoppingCartWrapper').find('.shoppingCartRemoveProductButton').on('click',function(){
        good_id = $(this).prev().prev().val();
        $.ajax({
          'url': remove_url,
          'type': 'post',
          'data': {'good_id': good_id},
          'success': function(data){
                $('#shoppingCartButtons').prevAll().remove();
                $('#shoppingCartButtons').before(data);
          }
        });
      });
    });
</script>
```

sorry for my bad english!hope I describe my question clearly,if not,I also put the code on line,the address: http://weixin.chenfw.me/mall/index.
please help me...

Comment: try change $('#shoppingCartWrapper').find('.shoppingCartRemoveProductButton').on('click',function(){ ... for.. $(document).on('click', '#shoppingCartWrapper .shoppingCartRemoveProductButton', function() { ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is selector for remove event.
You want to click on remove button but this button was appeared via dom, not document load.

Try change selector to document for listen event .on click selector_added.

```
$('#shoppingCartWrapper').find('.shoppingCartRemoveProductButton').on('click',fu‌​nction(){ ...
```

to

```
 $(document).on('click', '#shoppingCartWrapper .shoppingCartRemoveProductButton', function() {...
```

if i try run your ajax in console, it worked fine how you expect.

Comment: it can not work, I change my code as you say, when I click the remove button it can start a ajax request,but the good can not delete from the shopping cart,I still have to refresh the page

Comment: sorry, it's my fault.you way works fine,the question is I can not exactly get the good_id